# Needing an elegant solution to a simple, C++ bingo board

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I'm trying to code a Bingo Board in C++, but I'm doing something very wrong. I'm not sure what, but for whatever reason when I initialize the number of rows and columns, and do a nested for loop on the arrays I created to implement this structure, I get what appears to be more than a hundred rows and 30+ columns, when I should just be getting a five, by five board. I'm also trying to specify a max and min value for my rand function, but it appears that there isn't a way to do this. Thus, what would be the best approach to accomplish this without giving away the solution? The reason why I mention that last bit is so I can learn how to do this lol.

Here is my code:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Board
{
public:
    Board(unsigned int numberOfRows, unsigned int numberOfColumns, unsigned int seed, unsigned int max, unsigned int min);
    void generate();
        void setSeedValue(int seed);

private:
   unsigned int m_rows[];
   unsigned int m_columns[];
   unsigned int m_max, m_min;
};

#endif // BOARD_H

    Board::Board(unsigned int numberOfRows, unsigned int numberOfColumns, unsigned int seed, unsigned int max, unsigned int min)
{
    this->m_rows[numberOfRows];
    this->m_columns[numberOfColumns];
    srand(seed);
    this->m_max = max;
    this->m_min = min;
    printf("%d\n", size_t(m_rows));
    printf("%d\n", size_t(m_columns));
}

void Board::generate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_t(m_rows); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size_t(m_columns); j++)
        {
            this->m_columns[j] = (rand() % 10) + j;

            std::cout << this->m_columns[j];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Board * board = new Board(5, 5, time(NULL), 100, 1);

    board->generate();

    delete board;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Where's `Board`'s constructor defined?

Comment: Updated. Construct definition has now been added.

Comment: How did this compile yet all?

Comment: It didn't. There was still other issues beyond what I was addressing, though most of them have been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create the 2-dimensional board your wanting, where the size is input at runtime, you're going to have to actually dynamically allocate a board in memory ... you can't declare your board the way you've done in your class as zero-length arrays.

Code like this:

```
this->m_rows[numberOfRows];
```

does not initialize your array-size ... rather it actually attempts to access memory allocated at that offset from the start of `m_rows` ... that could cause a segmentation fault or some other undefined behavior due to accessing memory beyond the end of the class/structure type.

It would be much better, since you're using C++, to create your board class using the STL's `std::vector` container.  Your `Board` class would then look like the following:

```
class Board
{
    public:
        Board(unsigned int numberOfRows, unsigned int numberOfColumns, 
              unsigned int seed, unsigned int max, unsigned int min);

        void generate();
        void setSeedValue(int seed);

    private:
       vector<vector<unsigned int> > board; //use the STL vector container
       unsigned int m_max, m_min;
};
```

Then in your constructor, you would actually allocate the necessary memory (through the STL's vector container) that your board will take up:

```
Board::Board(unsigned int numberOfRows, unsigned int numberOfColumns, 
             unsigned int seed, unsigned int max, unsigned int min)
{
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        this->board.push_back(vector<unsigned int>(numberOfColumns, 0));
    }

    srand(seed);
    this->m_max = max;
    this->m_min = min;
    printf("%d\n", size_t(m_rows));
    printf("%d\n", size_t(m_columns));
}
```

Finally, your `Board::generate` function would now look like the following:

```
void Board::generate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->board.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < this->board[i].size(); j++)
        {
            this->board[i][j] = (rand() % 10) + j;

            std::cout << this->board[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems like a great solution, the only thing I'm seeing however which I don't understand is this line:         "this->board.push_back(vector<unsigned int>(numberOfColumns, 0));"
I fail to see how that argument in particular works, at least with the vector<unsigned int> (and a function to go with it???) being passed in there. Is it static?

Comment: we're calling `std::vector<vector<unsigned int> >::push_back` ... this requires us to pass-in a type of `std::vector<unsigned int>`.  The syntax `std::vector<unsigned int>(numberOfColumns, 0)` calls the constructor of `std::vector`, and passes in the arguments for the number of slots to create in the vector container, and what value to initialize those slots to.  So we're generating a temporary vector object for the columns that is copied into a row. Once you've initialized the slots, you can access them via the `operator[]` syntax, which is what I've done in the `Board::generate` function.

Answer (score 1):

Let your board class store the row size and column size that as member variables. Use those member variables as your upper bounds in your for loops in the member function generate(). Also, use a 2D array rather an 1D array, as this better represents the structure of a bingo board. Currently, your initialization of temporary size_t's in your for loops is not correct. The array name is acts as a pointer to the first element of the array -- so that variable you create is not giving you the length of the array. You have to store the length of arrays separately from the array itself (or use boost::array).